# Jquery selecting and clicking

Tags: jquery

I'm actually using an editable Telerik grid with ASP.NET MVC.  One of the columns on the grid contains a delete button and I want to click this button using my own button which is placed somewhere else.

Here is how I get a reference to the currently selected grid row:

```
var selectedGRIDRows = $('#GRID tr.t-state-selected');
```

If I place the following statement in my code:

```
alert(selectedGRIDRows[0].cells[17].innerHTML);
```

the alert will show me the following:
Delete

So how can I create my own jquery to click this button (Although I don't think it's really a button as it looks like a link styled to look like a button)?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

`$(selectedGRIDRows[0].cells[17]).trigger("click")` should do it.

As @Rory McCrossan points out, this won’t actually click the button. Since I haven’t used this Telerik grid I’m not sure what sort of element the button is, but insert a selector for it here:
`$(selectedGRIDRows[0].cells[17]).find("[selector for button]").trigger("click")`

Comment: That will trigger a `click` event on the `td`, not the button.

Comment: Though hopefully there’s a cleaner way to access the `Delete` button with a CSS selector or somesuch.

Comment: Awesome, thanks this does the trick.  I'm still a jquery rookie!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selectedGRIDRows[0].cells[17]).trigger('click');
```

That should work...

Comment: Doesn't this define the function that is clicked when I click on the cell?  I'm trying to click the cell button from somewhere external on the page.